# MS Word 2010 (VSTO) programmatically change page color

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, word-2010

I am trying to achieve this by this code:

```
        app.ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.Visible = Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
        app.ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Red);
        app.ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.Solid();
```

However that does not work. Has anyone have an idea how to accomplish such task?

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the background colour of the page, your code works as intended.

The background colour just won't show up in print view, and the background colour won't be printed. The background colour property in MS Word will change the background in Web View, which is handy if you want to view the Word Document in a Web Browser.

Generally, if you want to print on coloured paper, you would develop the paper separately and change the colour of the fonts on your Word Document appropriately.